# The right CMS for me AND my clients

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, symfony, content-management-system

I'm a webdesigner and, more than that, a web programmer. I've been in the business for a while, but so far staying far away from any CMS.

Lately I'm thinking of making things a little bit easier for us by using one. The twothat came to my mind were

- Drupal
- Wordpress

So far it looks that for any simple, rather static webpage it's probably easiest to just use wordpress. But I'm not sure of how customizable WP is when it comes to the templates and plugins like galleries (I like to use galleria), online shops, maybe even forums etc., and the other compare to it in those aspects.
I heard that Drupal demands a coding background, which obviously isn't a problem but rather a plus.

The most important part though still is: even if I can code myself, my clients can't. So far we would provide them with an admin area with a text editor, upload section etc. How 'idiotproof' can those two be for the client?

Thanks for any info & opinions :)

Comment: Uhm, Symfony is not a CMS but a programming framework.

Comment: [cms vs framework](http://www.forma-pro.com/cms-vs-framework)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that someone will come along and close the question as unconstructive for soliciting debate, but in the meantime, here are my two cents worth. It is quite easy to think along the lines of: client needs to update a basic site easily (probably WordPress - pretty foolproof) but what if... they want a gallery and then what if they want a shopping cart and what if... they want to stop an alien invasion. The point is features can be added later - you may as well save your time and your clients money and come up with an exact brief with them and work to it. Don't go for a really heavyweight solution based on what ifs.

All the solutions you have mentioned can acheive what you want, choose one that you are most comfortable working with and will be useful for other clients (a professional has a living to make - don't reinvent the wheel and learn a whole new CMS with each project).

Comment: hihi, thanks for those cents ;)

Answer (score 0):

Biased by experience, perhaps (building client sites in WP for 7 years), but I love WordPress for this, especially in the 3.x versions.

It can handle (gracefully!) just about anything you want to do using custom post types, custom fields, etc. Install "Advanced Custom Fields" and "Custom Post Types UI" plugins, get familiar with the template hierarchy, and everything gets awesome quickly (no more editing html in the rich text editor to add some classes to show things properly ::facepalm::).

Specifically to what you mention, there's a plugin which will show the built-in WordPress galleries using Galleria ([this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/galleria/), I believe).

[WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) is probably the best modern eCommerce framework for WordPress. WP-eCommerce works too, if WC is too nickel-and-dimey for you ;).

[bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) is pretty nice for simple forums, I'm sure there are more options.

So obviously an opinion, but I really like WP for rapid, flexible, client-friendly development, recommend it highly.